NSUrlErrorDomain -1004 on Django Backend hosted by AWS (Route 53 + ELB) on iOS
Noticed today that some users are getting NSUrlErrorDomain (code -1004) by accessing our website, which is managed by ECS + ELB (6 rules) + Route 53.
Obviously, those domains have ssl, but accessing the website on Safari and Firefox (iOS), I'm automatically redirected to the "http" version, making me get the "NSUrlErrorDomain" error. If I type the website starting "https", it goes normally, and it only happens on iOS (didn't test Android, but on Chrome doesn't happens), and also don't happen on Desktop, and on MacOS only happens using Safari browser.
Resume:

Happens on MacOS (Safari only)
Happens on iOS (Safari and Firefox)
Doesn't happens on Windows Desktop (Firefox and Chrome)
Doesn't happens on Android (Firefox and Chrome)

Any clue of what is that?

From what you said,

this seems to be more of a browser problem. More likely a cookie problem. The redirection to http:// directs us in that way. Found this post from 2008.


You can clear website data occasionally to improve Safari performance.

Go to Settings > Safari.
Tap Clear History and Website Data.
Tap Clear History and Data to confirm.


Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/102456
Also, if that doesn't solve your problem,

Considering your server is configured correctly, you mentioned "the website doesn't work on Safari/Firefox on iOS for some users".
This points us in a direction of MACOS/ IOS's Private Relay not sure how info is being relayed by the third party after apple; but you could also try temporarily turning it off see this, and then try accessing your website in private mode.


As a follow up, if any of the above directions work in chronological order, you could force refresh client cookies.
